# Return a value from a class into a form

Tags: vb.net

I am calling a function from a class where it will return on a label different colors depending on the value that shows on the label. Below is the method:

```
Function GetLabelColor(value As Integer) As Color
    If value <= 3.9 Then
        Return Color.Green
    ElseIf (value >= 4) And (value <= 6.9) Then
        Return Color.Orange
    ElseIf value >= 7 Then
        Return Color.Red
    End If
End Function
```

And then in the form I am using this code to call it:

```
Dim uicommon = New CommonUI()
Dim labelColor = uicommon.GetLabelColor(Integer.Parse(lblResultadoTotal.Text))

lblResultadoTotal.ForeColor = labelColor
lblGB.ForeColor = labelColor
```

But for some reason it will return me only the Green color even if the value is greater then 3.9. Do you have any solution who might help me?

Comment: What value are you actually passing to this method?

Comment: You *should* get an exception when trying to execute `Integer.Parse("3.9")`. Is it possible that you are ignoring exceptions? I suggest that you create a [mcve].

Comment: I have tried your code and I can't reproduce the problem. (Of course I pass a string that can be converted by Integer.Parse to an integer like "1" or "5" or "9") Note also that if you switch to a double value instead of integer, your code has a bug because a value of 3.91 (or 6.91) cause your code to fail

Comment: This code is unfit to do the job correctly, it returns nonsense when the value is, say, 3.95 or 6.95.  Start there first.  Use the debugger next.

Comment: @Steve this values come from my database, basically it will add a value after a insert it into the database

Answer (score 1):

The function below does the same thing as the one you provided but accepts a double that will allow for decimals such as 3.9 to be passed to it

```
Function GetLabelColor(value As Double) As Color

    If (value >= 4) And (value < 7) Then
        Return Color.Orange
    ElseIf value >= 7 Then
        Return Color.Red
    End If 
    Return Color.Green
End Function
```

If you only want integers (whole numbers) passed to it then you should not do comparisons like value <= 3.9 because an integer will never equal 3.9. Instead you could use this version;

```
Function GetLabelColor(value As Integer) As Color

    If (value >= 4) And (value <= 6) Then
        Return Color.Orange
    ElseIf value > 6 Then
        Return Color.Red
    End If 
    Return Color.Green
End Function
```

If you use a Double version of the method then you will need to parse your string value using this;

```
Double.Parse(lblResultadoTotal.Text)
```

If you are not getting the value you expect it is not a problem with your method but the value being passed to it. Try hard-coding a value to test this; i.e. replace Integer.Parse(lblResultadoTotal.Text) with an actual number e.g. 5 and see if you get the color you expect.

This shows a simple console application that can demonstrate it working for the value 10.4

```
Imports System.Drawing

Module Module1

Sub Main()

    Console.WriteLine(GetLabelColor(Double.Parse("10.4")))

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

Function GetLabelColor(value As Double) As Color

    If (value >= 4) And (value <= 6) Then
        Return Color.Orange
    ElseIf value > 6 Then
        Return Color.Red
    End If
    Return Color.Green
End Function

End Module
```

Comment: At the moment the value that I have on the label is 10.4 so in this case I should get the red color but instead I have the green color

Comment: Seems like it doesn't recognize that if statement and then it will just return the Color Green

Comment: I've edited my answer. When you say you still get green I am assuming that you are literally looking at the label and it appears green. If this is happening and you are sure of the value 10.4 then the problem is you are not setting your return value to the label color

Comment: I think that might be the problem. Because it always return the green color.

Comment: When I call this method in the form I should not call the value As Double?

Comment: if you have a value of 10.4 then you need to call with the Double version. 10.4 is not an integer

Comment: Where should I add this line of code `Double.Parse(lblResultadoTotal.Text)`?

Comment: Ok I got it. But I still can't make this wokr

Comment: I think that this problem comes from the function

Comment: In the example code you gave replace Integer.Parse(lblResultadoTotal.Text) with Double.Parse(lblResultadoTotal.Text) but make sure that you replace your version of GetLabelColor with the one I provided

Comment: I will update the post with everything I have at the moment

Comment: The labelColor always displays green color and I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

I guess you must use Double instead of Integer.

Comment: Need to change your parse as well.

Comment: Dim labelColor = uicommon.GetLabelColor(Convert.ToDouble(lblResultadoTotal.Text))

Answer (score 0):

> But for some reason it will return me only the Green color even if the value is greater then 3.9. Do you have any solution who might help me?

"Greater than 3.9" is not the same thing as ">= 4". In number theory, there are an infinite number of values between 3.9 and 4.0. The realities of binary floating-point representation changes that a little so that there are not actually infinitely many, but there are still a damned lot. Under no circumstances will the value 3.9 compare as >= 4.0.

If you want 3.9 to act like 4.0, then you should be rounding the values to whole numbers (integers). There is a built-in method to do that, named `Math.Round`. There is [an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef48waz8.aspx) that allows you to specify a value from the `MidpointRounding` enumeration, which controls how a number that ends in .5 should be treated. For example, `AwayFromZero` would round 2.5 to 4.0, while `ToEven` would round it to 3.0. For 3.5, the results would be the same in both cases.

```
Function GetLabelColor(value As Double) As Color
    Dim roundedValue As Integer = Math.Round(value, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
    If (roundedValue >= 4) AndAlso (roundedValue < 7) Then
        Return Color.Orange
    ElseIf roundedValue >= 7 Then
        Return Color.Red
    Else
        Return Color.Green
    End If
End Function
```

Note: You probably want to use `AndAlso` in your condition, rather than `And`. The results will be the same in both cases, but `AndAlso` and `OrElse` are the preferred *logical operators*. The `And` and `Or` operators are reserved for *bitwise* operations, which is not what you're doing here. And hardly ever what you will be doing.

Comment: So when I call it, I should use the same code that I have in the form?

Comment: If `lblResultadoTotal` has something with a decimal point in it, then yes, you should parse it as a double. Then round it to an integer if you want to treat it like an integer. If `lblResultadoTotal` is guaranteed to only contain integers, then you can just parse it directly to an integer and skip the rounding. Clearly that's not the case, as evidenced by the other discussion.

Comment: This label have double's too. So I should `Convert.toDouble`?

Comment: Either one will work. Generally `Double.Parse` is a better choice than `Convert.ToDouble`.